# Nasm assembler x64 compare input string

Tags: string, assembly, comparison, nasm, x86-64

**Compare the user input string with some values.**

In this case i want to compare the input string with the '2' and jump to the CvrtMInus if the input is '2'

but nothing happends any idea?

**For example the user put :**

*nasm -f elf64 -g inputCompare.asm

gcc -o inputCompare inputCompare.o

 ./inputCompare 2*

```
sys_Exit       equ     1 ;id codigos del sistema
extern printf

section .data
formatoChar: db '%c', 0AH,0
formatoDec: dq '%d', 0AH,0
formatoStr: db '%s', 0AH, 0
mayus: db "Convert MAYUS", 0AH,0
minus: db "Convert MINUS", 0AH,0
tipoCnvs: db "2",0x0A

section .bss

section .text
global  main

_exit:
mov     rax,    1       ; exit
mov     rbx,    0       ; exit status
int     80h

main:
;Get the input data

 mov rcx, rdi     ; argc
 mov r8, 0     ; offset
 add r8, 8 ; apunta al siguiente argumento
 mov rdx, qword [rsi+r8] ; argv



 mov [tipoCnvs],rdx;Store value in variable
   ;print input
   ;mov rdi, formatoStr ; first parameter for printf
   ;mov rsi, rdx ; second parameter for printf
   ;mov rax, 0 ; no floating point register used
   ;call printf  ; call to printf     

;Print input value

 mov rdi,formatoStr
 mov rsi,[tipoCnvs]
 mov rax, 0; no floating point register used
 call printf

; This is the Comparison part that I'm interested in

 cmp byte [tipoCnvs], '2'
 je CvrtMinus

 ;Convierte a Mayusculas
 CvrtMayus:
 mov rdi,mayus
 mov rax,0; no floating point register used
 call printf
 jmp _exit

 ;Convierte a Minusculas
 CvrtMinus:
 mov rdi,minus
 mov rax,0; no floating point register used
 call printf
 jmp _exit
```

Comment: formattoDec is declared as a dq (quad word). Should this be declared as db (byte) instead?

Comment: You can put db instead but dq (quad word) works too.  Note that tipoCnvs is db and the format could by a greater size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `tipoCnvs` contains a pointer to the string, so `cmp byte [tipoCnvs], '2'` compares the first byte of the pointer and not the string. You need to load it into a register because you need another level of indirection. Example:

```
mov rsi, [tipoCnvs]
cmp byte [rsi], '2'
```

The usual advice applies: learn to use a debugger so you can fix your own mistakes.

PS: When using the C library you should not invoke the exit system call directly. Normally you'd just return from main, or if you really need to then `call exit` from the C library. The system call terminates the program immediately, without letting the C library shut down properly. For example, you might lose some output that has not been flushed from internal buffers yet.